# ReactJS: counting viewed children in the parent class without knowing their status (receiving it from children)

Tags: reactjs

I have a search that fetches items and displays them. After a click on an item, it marked as viewed. And it is recorded to a database so some items are viewed without any clicks.

The goal is: count viewed items in the parent class (only items that are currently displayed)

How I do it: I trigger the function from the parent element which increments "viewed" variable.

The problem is: items fetched many times and sometimes you receive the same items as before, sometimes same + more additional items, sometimes completely new items.

I can't figure out when to reset count as on new fetch old items don't trigger "handleIsViewed". It collects viewed items from multiple fetches or shows 0 even one of the items viewed already, but didn't re-rendered on new fetch (as it was displayed before new fetch happened)

This is simplified version of the code I'm using:

```
export default function Results(props) {
    const [items, setItems] = useState([]); // items array
    const [viewed, setViewedCount] = useState(0); // this doesn't reset state when new fetch going

    // this will trigger fetch of new items
    const handleOnClick = () => {
        // setViewedCount(0); // when resetting viewed count here, on the new fetch with the same items it will stay 0 

        fetch("/getitems", {
            // skipped
        })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(
            (result) => {
                setItems(result.items);
            }
        );
    }

    // counting viewed matches (triggered in children)
    const handleIsViewed = () => {
        setViewedCount(prevState => {
            return 1 + prevState;
        });
    }

    // passing function "handleIsViewed" to items so they can trigger it
    let rows = [];
    for (let item of items) {
        rows.push(<Item key={item._id} {...item} handleIsViewed={handleIsViewed} />);
    }

    return (<div>
        <div>{rows}</div>
        <button onClick={handleOnClick}>Fetch items</button>
    </div>);
}

export default function Item(props) {
    const [viewed, setViewed] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        // checking if its viewed or no in db
        if (true == marked_viewed_in_database) {
           setViewed(false);
           handleIsViewed(props._id);
        }
    }, []);

    // click will mark item as viewed
    const handleClick = (evt) => {
        // if already viwed doing nothing
        if (viewed) return;

        setViewed(true);
        props.handleIsViewed(props._id);
    }

    return (
        <div onClick={handleClick}>item</div>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found:
I trigger handleIsViewed in the child outside of useEffect. In this case it will be triggered each time new items received, even some not rendered (because rendered before that).

In this case, the iterator provides duplicates on viewed data, so I store ids of each match in the set (and without using it as a state variable) and then use viewed.size to get viewed items count.

```
export default function Results(props) {
const [items, setItems] = useState([]); // items array
let viewed = new Set(); // will be resettings each time new fetch triggered

// this will trigger fetch of new items
const handleOnClick = () => {
    // setViewedCount(0); // when resetting viewed count here, on the new fetch with the same items it will stay 0 

    fetch("/getitems", {
        // skipped
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(
        (result) => {
            setItems(result.items);
        }
    );
}

// counting viewed matches (triggered in children)
const handleIsViewed = (id) => {
    viewed.add(id);
}

// passing function "handleIsViewed" to items so they can trigger it
let rows = [];
for (let item of items) {
    rows.push(<Item key={item._id} {...item} handleIsViewed={handleIsViewed} />);
}

return (<div>
    <div>{rows}</div>
    <button onClick={handleOnClick}>Fetch items</button>
</div>);
}

export default function Item(props) {
    const [viewed, setViewed] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        // checking if its viewed or no in db
        if (true == marked_viewed_in_database) {
           setViewed(false);
           handleIsViewed(props._id);
        }
    }, []);

    // sending data on each fetch update from the child
    if (viewed) {
        props.handleIsViewed(props._id);
    }

    // click will mark item as viewed
    const handleClick = (evt) => {
        // if already viwed doing nothing
        if (viewed) return;

        setViewed(true);
        props.handleIsViewed(props._id);
    }

    return (
        <div onClick={handleClick}>item</div>
    );
};
```